# Arithmetic structure including both unique factorization and Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains, dedekind-domain

Has an algebraic arithmetic structure been defined on integral domains, which would include both Dedekind rings and unique factorization domain with respect to the arithmetic properties, and more specifically with respect to the "unique decomposition" into prime objects?

Prüfer domains are too general and does not seem to provide the arithmetic.
Valuations on integral domains are good, but they allow only local arithmetic.

Comment: @rschiew. Thank you so many for this comment (please, make it an answer!). Krull domains are exactly what I intended to invent, before I realized that someone had probably done it before (hence the question).

Comment: done${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not clear on what “arithmetic” means here but I’ll suggest the following properties which may help you.

Krull domains generalize both UFDs and Dedekind domains, while atomic domains generalize UFDs by dropping unicity of decomposition.